# Average of Cells in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

New to VBA. Attempting to create macro that will fill a column (D) with the average values of another column (C). I created a variable `nb_rows` and have started with this code:

```
    Dim myRangeC As String
    Let myRangeC = "C4:C" & nb_rows

    For i = 4 To nb_rows
    Range("D" & i).Value = Application.Average(myRangeC)
    Next i
```

I am getting an error. Where have I gone wrong. Currently have nb_rows set to 27, for example.

Comment: Don't use `Let`, just do `Set myRangeC = "C4:C" & nb_rows`. Also you can't set a range to a string. You'll have to `Dim myRangeC As Range`

Comment: @dwirony still produced an error

Comment: What's the error? What is the value of nb_rows?

Comment: `Set myRangeC = Range("C4:C" & nb_rows)` with `Dim myRangeC As Range`

Comment: But you know this will fill all the cells in column D with the same value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work for me. It will place the average in every row in column D (I'm not sure if this is your intention, but it is how your code is currently structured).

```
Sub Test()

        Dim nb_rows As String
        Dim myRangeC As Range
        Dim i As Long

        nb_rows = 27

        'Change Sheet1 to your sheet name
        Set myRangeC = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C4:C" & nb_rows)

        For i = 4 To nb_rows
                Range("D" & i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(myRangeC)
        Next i

End Sub
```

Some things to note:

- Changed `myRangeC` from a `String` to a `Range`
- Set `myRangeC` using the proper procedure to declare and set a range (change Sheet1 to your sheet name)
- Changed `Application.Average` to `Application.WorksheetFuncion.Average` and passed in the range (it accepts a `Range` object, not a string)

I can provide more clarification if needed.

Comment: ^ This. Or `Set myRangeC = Application.Range("C4:C" & nb_rows)`

Comment: Agreed that you don't need the Worksheets qualifier. You can use `Application.Range` or even just `Range` as I did further down. I'm someone who tends to qualify my objects as much as I can to avoid unexpected results though!